# How to determine the reﬂecting horizontal hidden barrier for Ito diﬀusion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations, wiener-measure

The first article at the link below talks about that the Bi-Directional Grid Constrained (BGC) stochastic processes for a random variable X over time t is one in which the further it departs from the origin, then the further it will be constrained from above and below (bi-directionally) along that X dimension (see section "Definition 1.1. Bi-Directional Grid Constrained (BGC) Stochastic Process").

Section 5 (Conclusion) states "The net effect of the BGC operates as a reflecting horizontal hidden barrier, from which we derived a theorem for the logarithmic bounds of the resulting envelope."

**QUESTION: I would like to know how to determine the boundary level at which the random variable X is constrained?**

[Article - ITERATED LOGARITHM BOUNDS OF BI-DIRECTIONAL GRID CONSTRAINED STOCHASTIC PROCESSES](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/354921641_ITERATED_LOGARITHM_BOUNDS_OF_BI-DIRECTIONAL_GRID_CONSTRAINED_STOCHASTIC_PROCESSES)

There is a related article found here which may also add some background [BI-DIRECTIONAL GRID CONSTRAINED STOCHASTIC PROCESSES' LINK TO MULTI-SKEW BROWNIAN MOTION](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/360481490_BI-DIRECTIONAL_GRID_CONSTRAINED_STOCHASTIC_PROCESSES%27_LINK_TO_MULTI-SKEW_BROWNIAN_MOTION)

Answer (score 1):

Dr. Aldo Taranto here. As the main author of these journal papers, the random variable X is always constrained, except at the origin, and becomes increasingly constrained the further it departs from the origin. The journal paper [Hidden Geometry of Bidirectional Grid-Constrained Stochastic Processes](https://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/jps/2021/9944543.pdf) shows the formula of the hidden barrier for a certain type of geometric constraining regime, and a proof for the formula of this hidden barrier, although I have since written a more elegant proof.